# Compact support of the space of all Fields on a manifold $M$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, global-analysis

Let $M^n$ be a smooth Manifold, of dimension $n$.

From [*Kriegl, Andreas; Michor, Peter W.*, [**The convenient setting of global analysis**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/434294), Mathematical Surveys and Monographs. 53. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). x, 618 p. (1997). [ZBL0889.58001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0889.58001).]

> A section $u$ of a bundle $(p,TM,M$ where $p: TM \longrightarrow M; \quad \text{$p$ is a smooth map})$ is a smooth mapping $u: M \longrightarrow TM$, with $p \circ u =\text{Id}_M$.
>
> The support of the section $u$ is the closure of the set $\{x\in M \mid u(x) \neq 0_x\}$
> in $M$. $\big(\text{$0_x$ is the null vector in $T_x(M), x\in M$}\big)$
>
> Then the space of all such *smooth sections of bundle* $(p,TM,M)$ is denoted by
> $C^{\infty}(M \leftarrow TM)=\mathfrak{X}(M)=$ space of *all smooth vector fields* on $M$.

Again they define

> The space of all such *smooth sections of bundle* $(p,TM,M)$ **with *compact support***
> is denoted by $C_{\mathbf{c}}^{\infty}(M \leftarrow TM)=\mathfrak{X}_\mathbf{c}(M)=$ space of all smooth vector fields on $M$ with ***compact** support*.

Query:

1. What does ***compact** support* denotes here and what is the difference of
   $C_{\mathbf{c}}^{\infty}(M \leftarrow TM)=\mathfrak{X}_\mathbf{c}(M)$ with $C^{\infty}(M \leftarrow TM)=\mathfrak{X}(M)$?
2. Is it always necessary to have a compact manifold $M$ so that every element of $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ have compact support?

Comment: A section has compact support if its support is compact. The difference between X_c(M) and X(M) is that the first one is the space of fields with compact support, while the second one is the space of all fields. No, you cannot identity the two simply because when M is not compact there are fields with non-compact support.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Does $M$ has to be compact in order to have compact support of $\mathfrak{X}(M)$

Comment: There is no more elaboration than what I wrote above.

Comment: That paper you are reading is not exactly written for people who are not very familiar with all this. Why not start with some introduction to the subject, rather?

Comment: X(M) will never be compact. It is a vector space. What may be compact is the support of an element of X(M).

Comment: The elements of X(M) cannot be compact (that makes no sense, in fact) but their supports can be compact. Every element of X(M) will have compact support exactly when M itself is compact.

Comment: I understand what is the support of a vector field but I do not find what are the conditions on $M$
 for which every element of $\mathfrak{X}(M)$
 will have compact support.

(Sorry I wanted to mean compact support not compact, it was my typo)